# Billed Bytes on BigQuery: Billing Page is different from Audit Logging and INFORMATION_SCHEMA

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

I'm interested in knowing exactly how much each of my queries are spending on BigQuery. The problem is that the sum of billed bytes for the queries DO NOT add up to the bytes billed in the Billing page. The sum is ~10% less than I see on the Billing Page.

As suggested [in the official BigQuery Monitoring page](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/monitoring), I tried:

**Audit Log**: Creating a sink with Cloud Logs and after that summing the totalBilledBytes for each query collected by the logs.

[image: sink logs page]

**INFORMATION_SCHEMA view**: Querying the `INFORMATION_SCHEMA.JOBS_BY_PROJECT` dataset for the total_billed_bytes:

```sql
DECLARE timezone STRING DEFAULT "America/Sao_Paulo";
DECLARE gb_divisor INT64 DEFAULT CAST(POWER(2, 30) AS INT64);
DECLARE tb_divisor INT64 DEFAULT CAST(POWER(2, 40) AS INT64);
DECLARE cost_per_tb_in_dollar INT64 DEFAULT 5;

WITH q AS (
  SELECT
  DATE(creation_time, timezone) creation_date,
  FORMAT_TIMESTAMP("%F %H:%I:%S", creation_time, timezone) as query_time,
  job_id,
  total_bytes_processed / gb_divisor AS bytes_processed_in_gb,
  (total_bytes_processed / tb_divisor)*cost_per_tb_in_dollar AS cost_in_dollar,
  project_id,
  user_email,
  FROM 
    `region-us`.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.JOBS_BY_PROJECT
  WHERE
    DATE(creation_time, timezone) = "2023-06-02"
    AND project_id = <<my_project>>
  ORDER BY
    bytes_processed_in_gb DESC
)

SELECT SUM(q.bytes_processed_in_gb)
FROM q
```

But each of these solutions gave me an answer **~10% smaller** from the total BigQuery Analysis I see on Billing (below).

[image: billing page]

Am I doing something wrong in the calculations? Any idea of what's missing?